# How to append "&login_hint=user@gmail.com" to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker

Tags: c#, google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

I want to append the login_hint to an authentication request to Google.
I'm using the following code:

```
FileDataStore fDS = new FileDataStore(Logger.Folder, true);
GoogleClientSecrets clientSecrets = GoogleClientSecrets.Load(stream);
credential = GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
                                clientSecrets.Secrets,
                                scopes.ToArray(),
                                username,
                                CancellationToken.None,
                                fDS).
                                Result;
var initializer = new Google.Apis.Services.BaseClientService.Initializer();
initializer.HttpClientInitializer = credential;
```

Where do I pass this parameter so the mail address is appended before the browser opens?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

thanks for the hints by Zhaph!

My solution so far:

```
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Flows;
using Google.Apis.Auth.OAuth2.Requests;
using Google.Apis.Util.Store;
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Threading;
using System.Threading.Tasks;

namespace MyOAuth2
{
    //own implementation to append login_hint parameter to uri

    public class MyOAuth2WebAuthorizationBroker : GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
    {
        public new static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets,
            IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken,
            IDataStore dataStore = null)
        {
            var initializer = new GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
            {
                ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
            };
            return await AuthorizeAsyncCore(initializer, scopes, user, taskCancellationToken, dataStore)
                .ConfigureAwait(false);
        }

        private static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsyncCore(
            GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer initializer, IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user,
            CancellationToken taskCancellationToken, IDataStore dataStore = null)
        {
            initializer.Scopes = scopes;
            initializer.DataStore = dataStore ?? new FileDataStore(Folder);
            var flow = new MyAuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer, user);

            // Create an authorization code installed app instance and authorize the user.
            return await new AuthorizationCodeInstalledApp(flow, new LocalServerCodeReceiver()).AuthorizeAsync
                (user, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
        }
    }

    public class MyAuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    {
        private readonly string userId;

        /// <summary>Constructs a new Google authorization code flow.</summary>
        public MyAuthorizationCodeFlow(Initializer initializer, string userId)
            : base(initializer)
        {
            this.userId = userId;
        }

        public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
        {
            return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
            {
                ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
                Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
                //append user to url
                LoginHint = userId,
                RedirectUri = redirectUri
            };
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks Very Much for this implementation! Saved me tons of time.  Poor that Google didn't properly handle this in the first place.

Answer (score 0):

Looking [at the source code](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Requests/AuthorizationRequestUrl.cs) for the .NET library, that parameter isn't supported.

The following query string parameters are currently defined on the Authorisation Request Url:

```
[Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("response_type", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]

[Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("client_id", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]

[Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("redirect_uri", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]

[Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("scope", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]

[Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterAttribute("state", Google.Apis.Util.RequestParameterType.Query)]
```

Within the [`GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow`](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Flows/AuthorizationCodeFlow.cs) class (which is called by `AuthorizeAsyncCore` within the broker), the method `CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest` does indeed call `GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl` but it only sets the `ClientId`, `Scope` and `RedirectUrl`.

It looks like you'll need to write your own instance of the Broker service if you want to set the additional properties on that class.

Comment: okay thank you for the hint, but there is a attribute "login_hint" in the [source](https://code.google.com/p/google-api-dotnet-client/source/browse/Src/GoogleApis.Auth/OAuth2/Requests/GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl.cs). But how can I use this with GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker?

Comment: You'll probably need to formulate your own request then based on the GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequest rather than using the Broker helper class.