# Specify login_hint using .NET Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2

Tags: google-oauth, google-api-dotnet-client

Since the `Google.Apis.Oauth2.v2` in `GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync()` requests a uri to a static json file that contains the links and parameters to Google Oauth2 services, how can I specify the `login_hint` parameter if I happen to know that information ahead of time?

```
var credential = await GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker.AuthorizeAsync(
    new Uri("ms-appx:///Assets/client_secret.json"),
    myScopes,
    "user",
    CancellationToken.None);
```

Extract from `client_secret.json`:

```
"auth_uri":"https://accounts.google.com/o/oauth2/auth?login_hint=user@domain.com"
```

- How to specify the `login_hint` parameteron a per user basis?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [How to append "&login\_hint=user@gmail.com" to GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/27512300/how-to-append-login-hint-usergmail-com-to-googlewebauthorizationbroker)

Comment: Yes, that was it. I posted as an answer the code I wrote after using what you refered to.

Answer (score 1):

I ended up subclassing the Google web authorization broker like this:

```
public class MyOAuth2WebAuthorizationBroker : GoogleWebAuthorizationBroker
{
    public static async Task<UserCredential> AuthorizeAsync(ClientSecrets clientSecrets,
        IEnumerable<string> scopes, string user, CancellationToken taskCancellationToken)
    {
        var initializer = new MyOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow.Initializer
        {
            ClientSecrets = clientSecrets,
            Scopes = scopes,
            DataStore = new StorageDataStore(),
        };

        var installedApp = new AuthorizationCodeWindowsInstalledApp(new MyOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(initializer, user));
        return await installedApp.AuthorizeAsync(user, taskCancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
    }

    public class MyOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow : GoogleAuthorizationCodeFlow
    {
        private string loginHint { get; set; }
        public MyOAuth2AuthorizationCodeFlow(Initializer initializer, string loginHint) : base(initializer)
        {
            this.loginHint = loginHint;
        }

        public override AuthorizationCodeRequestUrl CreateAuthorizationCodeRequest(string redirectUri)
        {
            return new GoogleAuthorizationCodeRequestUrl(new Uri(AuthorizationServerUrl))
            {
                ClientId = ClientSecrets.ClientId,
                Scope = string.Join(" ", Scopes),
                RedirectUri = redirectUri,
                LoginHint = this.loginHint
            };
        }
    }

}
```

Comment: It seems like the right solution for now. The client library should provide a better way to add any url parameters in the future.

Comment: Do me a favor add it as an issue and link it https://github.com/google/google-api-dotnet-client/issues  Link your question.